# Keras 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a siamese network (by using triplet loss method). I just cannot make it train. After many tries, I guess that I have my problem in the generator (where I prepare the input data stream for training) but I could not localize the problem so far. HELP! :)

Here is my model definition (it is based on ResNet50).

```python
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model.get_layer('flatten_1').output
model_out = Dense(128, activation='sigmoid',  name='model_out')(x)
new_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model_out)
```

Here I define the model to be trained:

```python
anchor_in = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
positive_in = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
negative_in = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

anchor_out = new_model(anchor_in)
positive_out = new_model(positive_in)
negative_out = new_model(negative_in)

merged_vector = concatenate([anchor_out, positive_out, negative_out], axis=-1)
# Define the model to be trained
siamese_model = Model(inputs=[anchor_in, positive_in, negative_in],
                      outputs=merged_vector)
siamese_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.001), loss=triplet_loss)
```

To be able to train the model. I need to feed it with data with a generator and here is how I define it:

(Note that I intentionally put only 1 picture in each folder just to start with.. I will later increase the # pictures in each folder if I can make it work.)

```python
def generator_three_imgs():
    train_path = r'C:\Users\jon\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\E'
    generator1 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator2 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator3 = ImageDataGenerator()
    anchor_train_batches = generator1.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_A', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1)
    positive_train_batches = generator2.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_P', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1)
    negative_train_batches = generator3.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_N', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1)
    while True:
        anchor_imgs, anchor_labels = anchor_train_batches.next()
        positive_imgs, positive_labels = positive_train_batches.next()
        negative_imgs, negative_labels = negative_train_batches.next()
        concat_out = concatenate([anchor_out, positive_out, negative_out], axis=-1)
        yield ([anchor_imgs, positive_imgs, negative_imgs], 
               concat_out)
```

And finally, I try totrain the model as following:

```python
siamese_model.fit_generator(generator_three_imgs(),
                            steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=15, verbose=2)
```

which fails right away by giving the following error message:

```python
Epoch 1/15
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 1 images belonging to 1 classes.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7537b4595917> in <module>()
      1 siamese_model.fit_generator(generator_three_imgs(),
----> 2                             steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=15, verbose=2)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2228                     outs = self.train_on_batch(x, y,
   2229                                                sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 2230                                                class_weight=class_weight)
   2231 
   2232                     if not isinstance(outs, list):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1875             x, y,
   1876             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1877             class_weight=class_weight)
   1878         if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):
   1879             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     74         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     75         data = [data]
---> 76     data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
     77 
     78     if len(data) != len(names):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     74         data = data.values if data.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame' else data
     75         data = [data]
---> 76     data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
     77 
     78     if len(data) != len(names):

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

There is maybe someone out there who has more experience on this..?

---

I recognized that I pasted the wrong data above. But that still would not solve the problem. The solution Daniel Möller suggested below solved the problem.

There was a typo in the content of generator function above. The corrected one (incl. Daniel's suggestion below) looks as folowing:

```python
def generator_three_imgs(batch_size=1):
    train_path = r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\E'
    generator1 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator2 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator3 = ImageDataGenerator()
    anchor_train_batches = generator1.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_A', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    positive_train_batches = generator2.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_P', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    negative_train_batches = generator3.flow_from_directory(train_path+'\Ed_N', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    while True:
        anchor_imgs, anchor_labels = anchor_train_batches.next()
        positive_imgs, positive_labels = positive_train_batches.next()
        negative_imgs, negative_labels = negative_train_batches.next()
        concat_out = np.concatenate([anchor_labels, positive_labels, negative_labels], axis=-1)
        yield ([anchor_imgs, positive_imgs, negative_imgs], 
               concat_out)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your generator is using a keras function (for tensors) to concatenate numpy data.

Use `numpy.concatenate([anchor_labels, positive_labels, negative_labels], axis=-1)`.

Comment: Daniel Möller, you are a legend! :) It solved the problem. But am I not supposed to use the keras concatenate function there? I am a bit puzzled why numpy.concatenate solved the problem. My intention was to use the multi-input method with shared layers approach.

Comment: Keras models work with "tensors" (its a type of object). Numpy works with "numpy arrays" (another type of object). Input data (including data generated by generators) must be numpy arrays. When inside the model, data is tensors, then the output is numpy again. You can't use a tensor function for a numpy array, nor a numpy function for a tensor.

Comment: Clear. Thank you very much!